# running script over multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

My programming knowledge is weak at best. I would like to be able to run the below script over a few of my sheets in google-sheets. The sheets names would be "Liquor Room", "Mezz" "Cooler", "Bar", "Events", "Knots". They all would pull from the "codes" sheet. Thank you to anyone who can help me and explain it to me in simpleton terms.

---

```
var mainWsName = "Liquor Room";
var optionsWsName = "codes";
var firstLevelColumn = 1;
var secondLevelColumn = 2;
var thirdLevelColumn = 3;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2,1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();




function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 1){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 1){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
  }


}

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){

    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1]})
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }

}



function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){

    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r,firstLevelColumn).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }

}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please briefly describe what your script does, what you have tried to adapt to your needs as well a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to match multiple sheet names. Change lines 1, 7, 20 and 22 as follows:

```
const mainWsName = /^(Liquor Room|Mezz|Cooler|Bar|Events|Knots)$/i;
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (wsName.match(mainWsName) && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 1) {
  } else if (wsName.match(mainWsName) && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 1) {
```

You are using an `onEdit(e)` trigger which means that the code will run *every* time *any* value in the spreadsheet is hand edited. The `options` global variable is initialized *each* time with `Range.getValues()` which hurts your spreadsheet performance. You may want to move the definitions of `wsOptions` and `options` to inside of `applyFirstLevelValidation()` and `applySecondLevelValidation()`.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH!!!! YOU DID IT!